# Target everything in a class except the next element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my entire jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".details").hide();
    $("li").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("color","blue");
    });
    $("li").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css("color","black");
    });
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(".details").not(this.next()).slideUp();
    });
});
```

the only line not working is

`$(".details").not(this.next()).slideUp();`

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use slideUp() on every **li** with the **details** class except for the **li** that I just used slideToggle() on.

Comment: can you paste your html code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling `next()` inside `not()`, wrap (convert) `this` into a jquery selector.

```
$(".details").not($(this).next()).slideUp();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know `this` was jquery exclusive.